# Null reference exception while uploading a file using IE 11

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

In MVC, I have tried to create a multiple file upload option. It works fine in every other browser, but not in IE 11.

**HTML Part**

`<input type="file" id="FileUpload" name="FileUpload" class="" multiple="true" accept=".png, .gif, .jpeg, .jpg, .doc, .docx, .ppt, .pptx, .xls, .xlsx, .pdf, .txt" />`

**Controller**

```
if (FileUpload != null && FileUpload[0] != null)
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < FileUpload.Count; i++)
                        {
                            if (FileUpload[i].ContentLength > 0)
                            {
                                //string fileExtension = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(FileUpload[i].FileName);
                                string fileExtension = "." +FileUpload[i].FileName.Split('.')[1];
                                model.UploadFile.FileType = fileExtension;

                                //if (fileExtension == ".xls" || fileExtension == ".xlsx")
                                //{
                                //string filename =DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss")+FileUpload.FileName;
                                string[] stAFileName = FileUpload[i].FileName.Split('.');

                                string strFileName = stAFileName[0] + "_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmssfff") + "." + stAFileName[1];
                                string fileLocation = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Content/UploadedFiles/"), strFileName);

                                model.UploadFile.FileName = stAFileName[0];
                                model.UploadFile.FileSize = (Convert.ToInt32(FileUpload[i].ContentLength) / 1000).ToString();

                                try
                                {
                                    if (System.IO.File.Exists(fileLocation))
                                    {
                                        System.IO.File.Delete(fileLocation);
                                    }
                                }
                                catch
                                {
                                    //System.IO.File.Delete(fileLocation);
                                    //FileUpload.SaveAs(fileLocation);
                                }

                                FileUpload[i].SaveAs(fileLocation);
                                model.UploadFile.FilePath = "/Content/UploadedFiles/" + strFileName;
                                if (FileUpload[i].ContentLength > 0)
                                {
                                    if (data.RID > 0)
                                    {
                                        model.UploadFile.ReportId = data.RID;
                                        _reportProvider.SaveFile(model.UploadFile);
                                    }
                                }
                                //}
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

The only solution I have found is we can change the IE settings, but it is not possible for a large number of systems.

Is there any method to solve this issue

Comment: What does `but not in IE 11.` mean? What's the problem? `<input type="file" ` is an HTML tag that works in all browsers. It's not affected by the server.

Comment: `<input type="file"` is working but the file is not receiving at the controller

Comment: hit `F12` and check the console log and Network tab. It could be that the form isn't posted at all, or there's another error

Comment: On the other hand, if IE11 doesn't support the `multiple` attribute, there's nothing you can do. You'll have to find a different way to post mulitple files, perhaps through a jQuery plugin, Javascript library or your own Javascript code that creates and sends a POST request.

Comment: All other data is posted, only the uploaded files get failed.